# How to find the median of three numbers, if one of them appears twice?

Tags: statistics, median

How do you determine the median of three numbers where two of  the numbers are duplicated?

For example, $(6,6,3)$.

Comment: It is the duplicated element then

Comment: What's the meaning of the notation $n^=$?

Answer (score 10):

To find the median of any set of numbers, put them in order from smallest to greatest.  If a number occurs more than once, list it more than once.  The number in the middle is the median.  If there is an even number of numbers, the median is the average of the two numbers in the middle.  For your first example, we line them up: $3$,$6$,$6$.  Since $6$ is in the middle, it is the median.

Comment: Interesting. How does it fit with the fact that the median should split the values in 2  equal parts? I understand it's not possible with an odd number of values but the median of `3, 6, 6, 6` is `6` and only one value is lower than the median.

Comment: @EricDuminil The same can be said of $3, 6, 6, 6, 6$, which has an odd number of terms. It shows that the median is not always a useful number.

Comment: does it also mean that the usual definition is wrong?

Comment: @EricDuminil What do you mean by the "usual definition"?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The usual definition is that the median splits the data sample in 2 equal parts. See the first paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median for example.

Comment: I believe that the "parts" you are mentioning are sets and as per the definitions a set can't contains duplicate elements. In your example one set contains 3 and the other 6. The definition on wikipedia is the following: The median is defined such that no more than half the values are larger than, and no more than half are smaller than, the median. Pay attention to the words "no more than". It doesn't mean "exact half of the values". For example: the median of 1,2,2,3,4,5,8 is 3 and the two partitions have size 2 (1,2) and 3 (4,5,8) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate is your answer in all

Comment: That may be the median of the example given, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @cosimo193 Sure it does ... given any three numbers in which one of the numbers is duplicated, the duplicated one is the median. That isn't in any way specific to the example in the question.

Comment: @JimBalter I was being a bit pedantic; it is the answer in to "what is the median" in every case of a 3 element list with duplicated elements, but the question was "how do you determine [the answer]", so the answer to the actual question was "work it out like a normal median" as described in the j126 answer.

Comment: "pick the duplicate" is also an answer to how, in the 3 item case, which is all the question asked.